# JavaScript Sudoku solver. Where did the previous number come from?

Tags: javascript, solver, sudoku

I'm analyzing the bruteforce algorithm and have one question.

```
var solveSudoku = function (grid, row, col) { 
    var field = findUnassignedLocation(grid, row, col);
    row = field[0];
    col = field[1]; 
    if (row === -1) {
        if (!newGameStatus) fillTheDom(grid);
        return true;
    }

    for (var num = 1; num <= 9; num++) { 
        if (newGameStatus) { 
            num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9) + 1;
        }
        if (isValid(grid, row, col, num)) { 
            console.log(row + ' ' + col)
            grid[row][col] = num;
            if (solveSudoku(grid, row, col)) {
                return true;
            }
            console.log(row + ' ' + col)
            grid[row][col] = 0;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

var findUnassignedLocation = function (grid, row, col) {
    var foundZero = false;
    var location = [-1, -1];

    while (!foundZero) {
        if (row === 9) {
            foundZero = true;
        } else {
            if (grid[row][col] === 0) {
                location[0] = row;
                location[1] = col;
                foundZero = true;
            } else {
                if (col < 8) {
                    col++;
                } else {
                    row++;
                    col = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return location;
}
```

If there is no number to fill (every number is invalid) recursive function returns false, right? Then somehow resets the previous filled cell. How does it goes back to the last cell?

Answer (score 0):

Every time a function is called its states are saved (until all the following states have failed) and if they fail processor jumps back to last branch that has at least one yet un-failed state to go to and continues until the solution is found or everything fails.

*I can make a gif that would explain it as simple as I can, but I can only do that after work*

Answer (score 0):

Imagine recursion simply like formatting.

```
solveSudoku(firstCell)
# Context : Global
On the first cell :
From 1 to 9 :
Is 1 valid ?
Yes.
If solveSudoku(nextCell):
    # Context : We're in the loop of the first cell at iteration 1.
    On the second cell :
    From 1 to 9 :
    Is 1 valid ?
    No.
    Is 2 valid ?
    Yes.
    If solveSudoku(nextCell):
        # Context : We're in the loop of the second cell at iteration 2 which is in the loop of the first cell at iteration 1.
        On the third cell :
            From 1 to 9 :
            Is 1 valid ?
            No.
            Is 2 valid ?
            No.
            Is 3 valid ?
            No.
            ...
            Is 9 valid ? 
            No.
            Return false.
    solveSudoku(nextCell = thirdCell) returned false, going on the loop. <<<<<<<<< This is "How does it goes back to the last cell?"
    # Context : We're in the loop of the first cell at iteration 1.
    Is 3 valid ?
    Yes.
    If solveSudoku(nextCell):
        # Context : We're in the loop of the second cell at iteration 3 which is in the loop of the first cell at iteration 1.
        On the third cell :
            From 1 to 9 :
            Is 1 valid ?
            No.
            Is 2 valid ?
            Yes. <<<<<<< 2 is now valid and we can go on !
            If solveSudoku(nextCell):
                # Context : We're in the loop of the third cell at iteration 2 which is in the loop of the second cell at iteration 3 which is in the loop of the first cell at iteration 1.
                On the fourth cell...
```

As you can see the recursion goes deeper and can simply escape one level of depth to try another path.

Comment: So its like in javascript? Everytime when function is called execution content is created? Each execution content has own variables and states?

Comment: Yes absolutely. Every of these function calls is independant and has its own variables, it get passed params and that's it !